# Getting Wrong Result in Codeiginiter Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing the same problem and I searched google and found a question (answered & solved) at stackoverflow. But the solution did not solve my problem.

Can anyone tell me the issue.

The Stack Over Flow Question is : [Codeigniter Pagination bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408766/codeigniter-pagination-problem)

Only the difference with the above question is I am not using Query String.

Following is my Controller Code:

```
        // Pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('customer/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_records; // I have total 5 records
        $config['per_page'] = $limit; // I have set the limit "2" for time being
        $config['cur_page'] = $page;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

I am Getting the following result:

1 2 3 >

but on the "3" link I am getting Link to 4th page instead of 3rd.

Comment: what do you mean by you getting link of 4th page? what is the link?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ci/index.php/customer/index/2 => for Page # 2 and http://localhost:8080/ci/index.php/customer/index/4 for Page # 3